# Binding a key press event on a Canvas widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've binded a key to my canvas through:

```
self.canvas.bind("<w>", lambda event: self.canvas.focus_set())
```

Now, what do I do so when that key is pressed, it calls a specific action, like move an object up on the canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this my specifying new *coordinates* whenever you click for example the letter `W`.

[Here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html) you can find methods supported by canvas objects. There's one called `coords`, which allows you to specify the coordinates of an object through its `ID`. The ID is the value returned when you create an object, for example, when you create an `oval`:

```
oval_id = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

IDs are unique, so you can use them to move specifically one object.
You can for example `bind_all` the clicks of a certain letter (for example `w`) with a method, which moves our oval. The following is a full working example (I hate to use `global`, but in this case, I am using it for simplicity):

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # using Python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk  # using Python 2

def move(event=None):
    global x1, x2, y1, y2, oval
    if event.char == 'w':
        y1 -= 10
        y2 -= 10
        oval = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
        canvas.coords(oval_id, oval)

m = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(m)
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
x1, x2 = 50, 100
y1, y2 = 50, 100
oval = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
oval_id = canvas.create_oval(oval)
canvas.bind_all('<w>', move)  

m.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation you need the following:

1. If you haven't done so already, specify the key you want to bind as a pattern at the first parameter to self.canvas.bind().
2. The second parameter can be a lambda expression, a function or class method.

Example:

```
# Sample event handler
def handle_up_key(self, event):
    self.canvas.focus_set()
    # Do whatever else you want.

def __init__(self):
    self.canvas.bind("<Key-Up>", self.handle_up_key)
    self.canvas.bind("<KeyPress-Up>", ...)
    self.canvas.bind("<KeyRelease-Up>", ...)
    # And so for any key you want to map.
```

More info:

- http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/pydoc/Tkinter.Canvas.html
- http://effbot.org/zone/editing-canvas-text-items.htm

Comment: You might want to mention that the canvas also needs to have keyboard focus for it to be given the event in the first place.